# Smarty Streets CSS Adjustment for Verified tick

Tags: javascript, css, smartystreets

I am facing this strange problem; I am using Smarty Streets to verify addresses.  According to the documentation when you map fields with Smarty Streets API it automatically binds a verified tick mark with the zip field.

As you can see I am mapping 5 sets of fields in my code:

```
 var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
         key: htmlKey,         // An HTML key from your account
         debug: true,         // Show debug stuff
         waitForStreet: false, // Hides autocomplete suggestions until a street is entered
         AutoVerify:true,

         addresses:
         [{
             ID: 'Complainant1',
             street: '#complainantOneStreetAddress',
             city: '#complainantOneCity',
             state: '#complainantOneState',
             zipcode: '#complainantOneZip'
         }
         ,

         {
             ID: 'Complainant2',
             street: '#complainantTwoStreetAddress',
             city: '#complainantTwoCity',
             state: '#complainantTwoState',
             zipcode: '#complainantTwoZip'
         },

         {
             ID: 'Suspect',
             street: '#suspectStreetAddress',
             city: '#suspectCity',
             state: '#suspectState',
             zipcode: '#suspectZip'
         },

         {
             ID: 'Vehicle',
             street: '#vehicleOwnerAdddress',
             city: '#vehicleOwnerCity',
             state: '#vehicleOwnerState',
             zipcode: '#vehicleOwnerZip'
         },

         {

             ID: 'BusinessInfo',
             street: '#businessStreetAddress',
             city: '#businessCity',
             state: '#businessState',
             zipcode: '#businessZip'


         }

         ]

     });
```

The problem is that it is displaying 5 tick marks on one field, which are overlapping each other. The class name is `.Smarty-tag` for all ticks as it is being called through API.

How can I solve this problem? Only that tick should show with the field that is bound to it. Others should not.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HTML that you are binding to? In your previous question the answer that was provided showed a working example that did not have this issue so it would be helpful for you to provide what your actual HTML looks like

Comment: Please provide some HTML.